# swift set an table with autocomplete suggestions into a table view controller

Tags: ios

in my iOS app (swift 2) i would like to realize a textfield with autocomplete suggestions. this works already fine.

my problem is the layout.

i have a table view controller with one section and 3 cells.
in cell 1 is a container which includes the textfield with the table of suggestions. in cell 2 and 3 are only labels.

http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160128/vwaydpyc.png

This is the result:

http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160128/kz5bsurx.png

i would like to set the height of cell 1 as the same height of cell 2 and 3. and the suggestions should be "pop up" over all cells and not only in cell 1, where the rest will be not visible.

Have you any ideas?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,   UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var autocompleteTableView: UITableView!


var pastUrls = ["Men", "Women", "Cats", "Dogs", "Children"]
var autocompleteUrls = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textField.delegate = self

    autocompleteTableView!.delegate = self
    autocompleteTableView!.dataSource = self
    autocompleteTableView!.scrollEnabled = true
    autocompleteTableView!.hidden = true
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    autocompleteTableView!.hidden = false
    let substring = (self.textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring)
    return true
}

func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String)
{
    autocompleteUrls.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    for curString in pastUrls
    {
        let myString: NSString! = curString as NSString
        let substringRange: NSRange! = myString.rangeOfString(substring)
        if (substringRange.location == 0)
        {
            autocompleteUrls.append(curString)
        }
    }

    autocompleteTableView!.reloadData()
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return autocompleteUrls.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let autoCompleteRowIdentifier = "AutoCompleteRowIdentifier"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(autoCompleteRowIdentifier)

        let index = indexPath.row as Int
        cell!.textLabel!.text = autocompleteUrls[index]
    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell : UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    textField.text = selectedCell.textLabel!.text
}
}
```

Comment: If you need the suggestions table to be displayed over all the cell, don't add it in the Container view of cell1. You may need to change your approach and add the suggestions table as a subview of your main view (the view which contains your 3 cell table view)

Comment: how can i add a subview? programmatically or is it possible in storyboard, too?

Comment: i updated my code in post 1

Comment: It's possible to add the `autocompleteTableView` via programmatically and also through storyboard.  You may need to change your Main view controller from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController` which contains both the Tables as subviews. Then just keep an outlet of the `autocompleteTableView` and show / hide as required.

Comment: wow, this is very complicated for me. is it possible hat you can create this example for me and send me the files, so I can learn from this? I prefer  to generate the subviews via storyboard. thank you very much

Comment: nobody how can helps me?

Comment: Have a look at [MLPAutocompleteTextField](https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField).. this will give you an idea of how to implement autocomplete drop-down table.

Comment: thx, but is there a swift version available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MPGTextField](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mpgtextfield) is a Swift version of third party Drop down text field library.

And for future reference you can find great thrid party controls at [Cocoa controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/)

Comment: this solution i found for a few minutes, too.

Comment: but is there an way to set the MPGTextField for TextViews?